# Is it possible for iOS 8 and above (Using Swift) apps to create Custom Alarm Clock that is based on user's location

Tags: ios, swift, gps, alarm

as titled here's the context:

I am trying to do an iOS version of "Wakey: SG Bus Alarm", which is one of the many such Android apps in Google Play. Wakey is an app that wakes people up with alarm during a bus journey.

I am trying to do this, with the inclusion of subway / metro (It is commonly called as MRT in Singapore)

Specifically, the involved steps are:

1) User should enter its current location (Using GPS) and desired destination.

I have roughly figured out how to implement this by this project:
[LocationManager](https://github.com/varshylmobile/LocationManager)

2) App will plan and suggest the possible public transport route. (Apple Map's API on Public Transportation has not reach Singapore yet, but there are 3rd party APIs such as Onemap.sg)

3) User confirms one of the suggested route provided by this 3rd party API.

4) My App starts tracking user location, using GPS.

5) Alarm should ring at 1 subway station or bus stop before the destination.

Problem is, I have read some of the previous threads about Alarm Clock and I have noted that since iOS7 onwards, the background app is limited to that few categories.

[Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1)

Given that I believe my proposed app falls under *Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app*, so I would like to know where to get started on the following points:

1) Alarm Clock written in Swift, because all I saw was Objective C for iOS5 or 6.

2) Some snippets for Background Thread if using it is necessary from the above context.

3) How to execute a function within a UIViewController whenever it is showing. Currently, I put some of these codes under viewDidLoad() and hence the code only run once during the first load of the UIViewController.

My app happens to have 4 tabs. There are some codes that I want it to run whenever the 2nd tab loads. But when I put these codes on viewDidLoad(), it only load once. So the code would not execute again, if I do in these steps accordingly:
- Load the App
- Change from default to 2nd tab
- Code Executed
- Change from 2nd tab to any other tabs (1st, 3rd or 4th)
- Change again to 2nd tab
- Code in viewDidLoad() *does NOT execute*

Thanks a lot if any kind heart soul can tell me if this kind of app is technically feasible or not in iOS.

Comment: For a tab view, each tab's `viewDidLoad` will normally just be called once and kept in memory for future usage. So it you want to some method been called every time it's been activated, better try `viewWillAppear`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.
There is nothing that hinders you to develop such an app.
First find out where to get the cooridnates for the bus stations.
As first step you can try OpenStreetMap.
The app is one part, the other main question is where to get that coordinates.